# Continuous key press event in Silverlight application

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, keypress

I am making application using silverlight.Here i want to move line on screen continuously on left and right arrow key pressed. In silverlight application there is facility of RepeatButton but i am not getting how to use it. Please help me if there is any solution on that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An easier method would be to have (bool) flags like "keyLeftPressed" and "keyRightPressed". Then, on a specific tick (from a `DispatchTimer` possibly), check if the flags are set and take appropriate action. Finally, use four events to set the condition of the two flags: left key pressed, left key released, right key pressed, right key released.